# how can i Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked in angular 13 with spring boot 3

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i'm calling an api in angular (the login and register work perfectly) but when i try to get some videos i get this error :

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8081/videos/allVideos' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

this is the cors config in spring boot :

```
      @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .maxAge(3600L)
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
```

and this is the video service in angular :

```
export class VideoService {

  private url = "https://localhost:8081/videos/";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getAllVideos(): Observable<Array<VideoPayload>>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<VideoPayload>>(this.url + "allVideos");
  }
}
```

also this works in postman so i assume that it may be a problem from angular

Comment: Can you show more of the class that has addCorsMappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the right code to make it work, i fixed the problem by adding this code in spring security config file inside the :

`http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().cors().configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() { @Override public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) { CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration(); config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200")); config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*")); config.setAllowCredentials(true); config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*")); config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization")); config.setMaxAge(3600L); return config; } })`

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why but it seems like a but that i fixed after rebuilding the project couple of times

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).